# Adjust size of R Markdown gt output

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt

I write almost all of my code in R Markdown documents and typically output to Word. I prefer to use the `gt` package to generate summary tables.

I can get a given `gt` object to output by using `gtsave` as a `.png` file. However, I can't change the size of the output with the code chunk settings (`{r fig.dim = c()}`).

I know I can change the size of the saved table in my working directory by using the `vwidht`/`vheight` functions, but is there a way to also change the size of the outputted tables within the R Markdown, itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **gt** package has it's own table formatting functionality, I was able to use the below code to change the size of the outputted table within Rmarkdown itself. You will have to [check the documentation](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_options.html) for more details, by default, numeric numbers used in the arguments below are considered pixel width and height.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
date: "9/25/2021"
output: html_document
---


```{r cars}
library(gt)
gt(mtcars) %>% tab_options(.,     container.width = 500, container.height =     500)
```
````

Below, the container arguments set to 500x500

[image]

now, the container arguments are set to 100x100

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @Daniel Jachetta!

Comment: Is there a way to define the tab options for the entire Rmarkdown document?  It would be very convenient if I could define this in for example the setup chunk instead of having to specify the width for each table.

Comment: you could probably set global chunk options, but I'm not sure if you have different sized tables how the would look. You could also look into CSS style options for figures and have the Rmarkdown document output HTML docs